# Checking the equality of means, P-value or CI

Tags: p-value

Among P value and confidence interval of the difference between two means, which one provides more accurate information for rejecting/accepting the equality of means?

Comment: the two are equivalent

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "more accurate". In general they should both give the same decision (there can be exceptions when asymptotic approximations don't quite correspond, for example with a p-value and CI for a normal approximation to a binomial proportion

Comment: @Glen_b, Thanks for the comment. I was wondering what is the advantage of looking at the CI regarding accepting/rejecting hypothesis? Some people believe that we should not reject/accept the hypothesis by  P-values.

Answer (score 1):

If *all* you're doing is deciding whether to reject or not, it makes no difference (aside some possible minor exceptions I already mentioned in comments); there's no benefit to using CI's for that reject/don't reject decision.

The real point about using CI's rather than p-values is that they tell you more than just whether your reject or not -- it's an interval estimate of the effect.

For example, with a test of equality of two means, concluding that the means differ is less informative than an interval estimate of the difference in means - consider the information that an interval like $(4.6,12.1)$ vs one like $(0.3,42.4)$ give you.